# AWS Elastic Beanstalk constantly fails to update the latest Git commit?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have an Elastic Beanstalk instance running in the Virginia region. The instance is running Amazon Linux with Node.js. We use Git as our Version Control System and the command line to push the latest build of our Node.js app to Elastic Beanstalk. We use the `eb push` command to push the app.

While the app is being pushed, it times out since it takes REALLY long to push the app and the new version never gets deployed. This has been an issue over the last few days that we just can't seem to fix. Here's a screenshot of the error log:

[image: File Log]

When I terminate the instance and start a new one, the latest Git commit does get deployed. However, subsequent commits never deploy. What can I do to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you snapshot the logs? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html

Comment: @RohitBanga Here are the last 100 lines: http://codeshare.io/NZbPR. I do have more comprehensive logs but I'm not sure I can easily share that here since there isn't any attachment option. If you do need those, I'm happy to send you an email or private chat.

Comment: How big is the version you're sending? We ran into this with a HUGE zip file since it had the node_modules folder. Try putting node_modules into the .ebignore file and adding the compilation steps in the deploy script.

Comment: @MarcYoung The build isn't that big. node_modules is ignored in Git. Does that mean it still gets pushed to EB?

Comment: @RohitBanga Did you get a chance to look at those logs? Thanks.

Comment: when something is deployed, it's packaged "as-is". So if it's from ci after doing npm  install, the node_modules exists and *might* go with it. EB deploy follows gitignore, but it's just good to check and make sure the version being deployed doesn't have extraneous things not needed for deployment such as docs, artifacts, etc.